# How to plot a parametric region representing a coordinate transformation

Tags: plotting, coordinate-transformation

The [Wikipedia page on Rindler coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates) shows a nice example of how a coordinate transformation can be represented in a plot.

They start with two coordinates $T,X$ with $0 < X < \infty,\; -X < T < X$. Then, they introduce two new coordinates $t, x$ by

$\begin{align*}t &= \mathrm{artanh}\left(\frac{T}{X}\right) \\ x &= \sqrt{X^2-T^2}\end{align*}$

From the plot below, it is clear how curves of constant $x$ and constant $t$ run in the old coordinate system:

[image: Coordinate transformation from (T,X) to (t,x)]

How could you make a clear plot like this with *Mathematica*? I would like to include the labels as well.

I guess you need the inverse transformations to express T and X in terms of t and x. I entered them below

```
T = x Sinh[t]
X = x Cosh[t]
```

Comment: What does t = infinity mean here? As I understand arctan(T/X) runs merely from -1 to 1, and so t from -Pi/4 to Pi/4 ... ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By `ParametricPlot`:

```
ParametricPlot[{x Cosh[t], x Sinh[t]}, {t, -Pi/4, Pi/4}, {x, 0, 4}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1.5}, {-1, 1}}, BoundaryStyle -> Dashed]
```

[image: mesh lines for Rindler coordinates]

or, for fun:

```
ParametricPlot[{x Cosh[t], x Sinh[t]}, {t, -Pi/4, Pi/4}, {x, 0, 4}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 1.5}, {-1, 1}}, 
BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red, Dashed],
PlotStyle -> Pink, PlotPoints -> 40, 
MeshShading -> {{Pink, Lighter[Red, 0.8]}}, Mesh -> 32, Frame -> False]
```

[image: another Rindler mesh]

Comment: But, where are the labels for the various lines? :) (+1)

Answer (score 4):

```
Plot[{
  Table[Tan[t] X, {t, -Pi/4, Pi/4, Pi/16.}],
  Table[sign Sqrt[X^2 - x^2], {x, 0, 5}, {sign, {-1, 1}}]}, {X, 0, 5},
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Basic plot only.

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be something wrong with the [image linked in the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pj00M.png).  In the Wikipedia article, they define the coordinates with a parameter `g`:

```
rindlerXT[x_, t_, g_] := {x Cosh[g t], x Sinh[g t]};
```

But the image appears to be for `g = 1/2`, not `g = 1` as claimed.

First, here is a labeling function.  Nothing special -- it seemed convenient to put it in its own place.

```
labels[g_] := {Table[
    Text[x == x0, rindlerXT[x0, 0.1 x0 + ArcSinh[0.16]/(g x0), g], {0, -0.5}, 
      D[rindlerXT[x, t, g], t] /. {x -> x0, t -> ArcSinh[0.16]/(g x0)}],
    {x0, 0.2, 1, 0.2}],
   Table[Text[t == t0, rindlerXT[Cos[g t0], t0, g], {0, -0.8}, 
      D[rindlerXT[x, t, g], x] /. {x -> Cos[g t0], t -> t0}],
    {t0, -1/g, 1/g}],
   Black, Text[x == 0, {0.16, 0.16}, {0, -0.7}, {1, 1}], 
   Text[t == Infinity, {0.75, 0.75}, {0, -0.7}, {1, 1}],
   Text[t == -Infinity, {0.75, -0.75}, {0, -0.8}, {1, -1}],
   Thick, Arrowheads[{-0.07, 0.07}], 
   Arrow[{{0, 1.19}, {0, 0}, {1.19, 0}}],
   Text[Style["T", Italic, Large], {0, 1.2}, {1.8, 1.5}],
   Text[Style["X", Italic, Large], {1.2, 0}, {1.5, 1.5}]};
```

I thought I'd show another way to get the grid.  I join a couple of larger values of `t` to the ends of the grid to make sure the curves do not stop short.  There are also some extra points in the `t` direction (constant `x`) so that the curves look smooth.  The grid of points generated by `Table` conveniently contain the lines we wish to plot.

```
rindler[g_, extraTPoints_: 3] := 
 Module[{color = Blend[{Red, Magenta}], tLines, xLines},

  xLines = 
   Table[rindlerXT[x, t, g], {x, 0., 1.2, 
     1/20}, {t, ({-10, -5}/g)~Join~
      Range[-Ceiling[4/g], Ceiling[4/g], 1/(8 extraTPoints)]~
      Join~({5, 10}/g)}];
  tLines =(* skip extra points t = -10, -5 and the extra intermediate points *)
   Transpose[xLines][[3 ;; ;; extraTPoints]];

  Graphics[{
    Lighter[color, 0.7],
    Thin, Line[xLines], Line[tLines],
    Thick, Line[xLines[[1 ;; ;; 4]]], 
    Line[tLines[[1 ;; ;; 4]]],
    {Black, Thick, Dashed, Line[{{1.5, -1.5}, {0, 0}, {1.5, 1.5}}]},
    color, labels[g]},

   PlotRange -> {{-0.15, 1.18}, {-1.2, 1.2}}, 
   PlotRangeClipping -> True, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None, 
   FrameLabel -> {{None, None},
                  {Row[{"g = ", Sequence @@ If[g == 1, {1}, {"1/", 1/g}]}], None}},
   ImageSize -> 250, BaseStyle -> 13]
  ]

Row[rindler /@ {1, 1/2}, "  "]
```

[image: Plots of Rindler coordinates with g = 1, 1/2]